# How to add border to nested text component?

Tags: react-native

I have three parts of the text wrapped inside a bigger text component, and together they form a paragraph. How do I put border on one of the children text component?

I want my three parts of text to form a paragraph without new line in between and that's why I utilized nested text here.

I tried to just add borderWidth and borderColor etc. They work by themselves but not in nested text component.

```
<Text style={styles.text}>
    <Text> first part of the text </Text>
    {/* this doesn't show border  */}
    <Text style={{
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderRadius: 12, padding: 8, color: '#577FFF',
      }}>
       middle part of the text 
     </Text>
     <Text> last part of the text </Text>
 </Text>

{/* this works fine  */}
<Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#000', borderRadius: 12, padding: 8 }}>Test text</Text>
```

I expect the middle part of the text is wrap inside a border. It doesn't have to be a nested text structure. If anything else that can achieve this result is fine! Thanks!

Edit: Desired effect is like this: [snack.expo.io/Hy3ic16bB](http://snack.expo.io/Hy3ic16bB), but this only works in web, not on ios

Comment: Have you tried wrapping them in Views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the wrapper to a View. A Text component should only hold text.

https://snack.expo.io/B1vAnjjZH

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> first part of the text </Text>
                {/* this doesn't show border  */}
                <Text style={{
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'black',
                    borderRadius: 12, padding: 8, color: '#577FFF',
                }}>
                    middle part of the text
                </Text>
                <Text> last part of the text </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I need three part of the text to be on the same line though. In this case, three parts of the text are on three different line

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't make it clear. My desire effect is like:
' Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s' where the word standard should have the border but the text as a whole should just read like a big chunk of text. Using flex box will make the it three separate part.

Comment: Desired effect is like this: https://snack.expo.io/Hy3ic16bB, but this only works in web, not on ios

Comment: I changed the snack a little bit https://snack.expo.io/SJcAUOwXS. Is it possible to make the number be consecutive?